# Splitting of a huge data and looping the same code for all chunks of data

Tags: python, pandas, loops

My Problem is a little tricky. I've broken down my huge data file in chunks and applied a fuzzy-wuzzy code to each chunk multiple times. After that, I collate the result into one file. I am wondering if some kind of loop can be applied to re-use the code instead of writing it for each variable. Below is the example.

```
df = pd.read_csv('dec 10.csv')
df1 = df.iloc[0:20000]
df2 = df.iloc[20000:40000]
df3 = df.iloc[40000:60000]
match1 = df1['Customer Name'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df1['Customer Name'].values, n=2, cutoff=0.8)).apply(pd.Series).dropna(axis=0)
match2 = df2['Customer Name'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df2['Customer Name'].values, n=2, cutoff=0.8)).apply(pd.Series).dropna(axis=0)
match3 = df3['Customer Name'].map(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, df3['Customer Name'].values, n=2, cutoff=0.8)).apply(pd.Series).dropna(axis=0)


a = match1.append(match2, ignore_index =True)
b = a.append(match3, ignore_index =True)
```

I am looking for an optimized way to write the match code once instead of writing it for each chunk of data and then collate it later.

Comment: That's exactly what functions are there for. Are you familiar with how functions work? In your example even a simple for-loop could help.

Comment: yeah, I am could write straight codes but not functions. Checking right now and would give it a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you can split up something into groups of length `n` like this

```py
dfgroups = [df[x:x+n] for x in range(0, len(df), n)]
```

Substitute `20000` in for `n` and you'll get chunks of at most 20,000 each. You can then loop your code for each item in `dfgroups`. Also you'll want `matches` to be its own list that you can append to. And lastly, for readability, for a line that long, you probably just want to write a `mapper` function rather than use a massive lambda.

Putting this all together, your code can be rewritten like this.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('dec 10.csv')

# split df into groups of 20,000
dfgroups = [df[x:x+20000] for x in range(0, len(df), 20000)]
matches = [] # empty list to store matches

for dfgroup in dfgroups:

    # a function to replace that long line, more readable
    # this function will get redefined every loop, using the new `dfgroup` each iteration
    # this is optional, and you can instead keep that long line, replacing `df` with `dfgroup`
    def mapper(x):
        values = dfgroup['Customer Name'].values
        result = difflib.get_close_matches(x, values, n=2, cutoff=0.8))
        result = result.apply(pd.Series)
        result = result.dropna(axis=0)
        return result

    match = group['Customer Name'].map(mapper) # passing the function as an argument rather than using a lambda
    matches.append(match) # append it to the matches list
```

Now `matches` is equivalent to `[match1, match2, match3, ...]` and can be used like `matches[0]` `matches[1]` etc

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over a list of dataframes, so that at each iteration you simply refer to `df` and avoid duplicating code:

```
match = pd.Dataframe()
for df in [df1,df2,df3]:
    match_ = df['Customer Name'].map(lambda x: difflib
                 .get_close_matches(x, df['Customer Name'].values, n=2, cutoff=0.8))
                 .apply(pd.Series).dropna(axis=0)
    match = match.append(match_, ignore_index =True)
```